# How to disable fork on private repo on github

Tags: github, enterprise

It was easy on bitbucket. if I dont want my repo to be forked. I can disable it. Only people I have invite can work on repo as long as they have permission on repo.

But where is that functionality in github. I have enterprise repo and I want invite people work on it. but dont want them to fork it.

I might have missed something, google search didn't bring anything useful. 
Can anybody point me in right direction please ?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 18):

GitHub doesn't have such a feature as Bitbucket has, but still, you can't make fork from a private repository public. You'll see this message:

```
Private forks can't be made public.
```

It gives you a "fool protection" when somebody want's to publish your private repo. Of course, if somebody really want's to do this, they always can push all the code to some new repo as @Chris stated above.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not aware of any way to do this in GitHub, and frankly I don't see any value in Bitbucket letting you "disable" forking, either.

Bitbucket may let you disable the fork *button*, but anybody who can clone your repository can "fork" it by simply pushing it up to a different remote:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:alix/some-repo.git
git remote set-url --push origin git@bitbucket.org:chris/some-repo.git
git push origin master
```

Comment: Well yeah that make sense. I guess that why github didnt put it there. lol

Comment: Even the so called "private" repos are not protected. If you can clone, you can upload elsewhere.

Comment: As the company github administrator.... we have very novice users who make these kinds of mistakes (example: forking repositories instead of cloning locally). Fortunately I get a warning email so I can track them down. We could use the feature.

Comment: But Github Enterprise/Org has this feature to disable fork per repo and also on the entire organization. Why can't you simply disable fork?

Answer (score 11):

Github has this functionality now. See [Github's howto](https://help.github.com/articles/allowing-people-to-fork-a-private-repository-owned-by-your-organization/) -- note that (as requested by OP) this is only available for private repos of organizations.

To access this setting you must be signed in as an organization owner or as a repo admin. Navigate to your repo > Settings > Options and uncheck "Allow forking"

[image: Allow forking location]

Additionally, you can set this setting for your entire organization. Go to your organization settings then Member Privileges and uncheck the Repository Forking option.

Comment: @MichaelChirico I have confirmed that this feature does still exist in the same location. Are you trying with a public repo? This is a private repo only feature.

Comment: Indeed you're right. I wasn't reading carefully enough. I added some emphasis for any future readers like myself. thanks!

Comment: Note that forking a private repo creates a private fork with the same permissions, so disabling forking is more of a cosmetic / "procedure enforcement" thing than anything else.

Comment: No such option. Only Wiki, Issues, Sponsorships, Project and Discussions are there and not to mention completely different UI.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar This options still exists. This option is available for organizations and private repositories only.

Comment: @Clint No, as per their own docs, this option is not available for private repositories of users anymore, only private repositories of organizations have this feature now.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Clint this is what i found from github docs

> An organization owner must allow forks of private repositories on the
> organization level before you can allow or disallow forks for a
> specific repository.