# Is there a way to avoid forks on a bitbucket repository and allow only branches

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket

I have a bitbucket repository, I dont want anybody to be able to FORK it but I need them to be able to create a BRANCH.

If bitbucket does not support this does github or any other repo supports this ?

My original question is for BITBUCKET and the "duplicate" question has no accepted answer and is obsolete

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable fork on private repo on github](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405399/how-to-disable-fork-on-private-repo-on-github)

Comment: Bitbucket does (or did in 2010).

Comment: the "duplicate" questions is about GITHUB not BITBUCKET

Comment: The duplicate question starts with "It was easy on Bitbucket". But you are right, it's not an exact duplicate. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the bitbucket website, go to the settings of your repo / Repository Details, set Forking : "No Forks"