# How to give team members permission to upload their contrinbution on specific part of project on Github?

Tags: git, github

I'm new to version control so my team's project is divide into multiple parts.

Is there a way to give my team members access to modify and upload their contribution to their individual section of the project using access token?
I don't want to give them access to Edit anything outside of their scope, if you know what I mean.
**Update:** 
[image]
 I'm using submodule in the MainProject, and the MainRepo has multiple subRepos, and each dev has access to one of these subs but not all, as following:

```
MainRepo/ contains (Rep1/ & rep2/ & rep3/)
and
Dev1->rep1
Dev2->rep2
Dev3->rep3.
```

What I want to do is that dev1 Should be able to modify rep1 and readonly the other repositories.

According to what I understood from Von's answer is that if dev1 is forking the mainproject, he can modify rep2 as well and make pull request to the maintainer, which is what I want to avoid. What I want is even though dev1 can do modification on rep2 locally, he cannot ask the maintainer to make any change on dev2's repository(I want to force dev1 to call dev2 and request change from him first)

Comment: Have you ever tried [GitLab](http://about.gitlab.com)? I believe it's better than GitHub to contributing to projects in a team basis. It's worth a try! :)

Comment: Nope, I'm new to source control, is it better than gitbucket for my question? if so how. Thanks

Comment: Look, this is not about merchandising or so, ok? It's just a suggestion. Their workflow is very impressive and effective via fork-fetch-push-merge request-review-merge. If you want you can even install it to your own server, for free - it's open source. Google for "GitLab workflow" if you want an overview. Tomorrow I can try to give you some links if you need. Anyway, I gave them a try and I'm very well surprised with the results.

Comment: Being more specific, what I think could be helpful regarding your question is: you can make groups and give restrict access to people, you can  have private repos (free), you can protect branches, you can work with merge requests, you can assign jobs, open milestones... There's a lot of things to work with. Better take a look by yourself to see if would be helpful in your case. I think it would, but it's up to you taking some time to read about it and to try it. GitLab.com is free to use and fully featured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to decompose your project into different git repo, and asking your team to fork the repo they need to work on.

With the [forking workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/forking-workflow), you are in control of the pull requests, so even if they are working on the wrong repo, they won't be able to integrate their modification to the actual original repo.

[image: https://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/Article-Images/9479_08_01.png]

(<sup>Source: "[Using Gerrit with GitHub](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/using-gerrit-github) - Luca Milanesio"</sup>)

Comment: Thanks but it helps a bit but i don't think this is what i want i updated my question to explain more, feel free to answer my question there.

Comment: @ma1169 that is still ok: forking the main project does not mean forking dev2, which mean the developer won't be able to make pull request directly from that fork. He/she would have to fork directly dev2 [which you cannot prevent in GitHub, you can in BitBucket](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29117673/6309). And you can easily filter out any PR on dev2 coming from the wrong dev.

Comment: @ma1169 all repos mentioned here are git repo (either cloned locally or hosted on GitHub)